# Coercivity of inverse operator

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose that $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ satisfies:
$$
m \|u\|^{2}_{2} \leq \langle u,Au\rangle \leq M\|u\|_{2}^{2} \text{ for all } u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}
$$
but is not necessarily symmetric. By coercivity we have that $A^{-1}$ exists and is bounded:
$$
\|A^{-1}u\|_{2} \leq \frac{1}{m}\|u\|_2
$$
(I think this is just a simple version of the Lax-Milgram theorem). Can one say anything about the coercivity of $A^{-1}$? Specifically, if $A$ were symmetric and diagonalizable then one could say that:
$$
\|A^{-1}u\|_{2} \geq \frac{1}{M}\|u\|_2
$$
Is this true when $A$ is non-symmetric?

Comment: Are you assuming $A$ is linear? If so, "continuous" is superfluous.

Comment: Yes I am, and you're right. I will edit the question. I guess my primary question is what, if anything, does the upper bound $M$ say about a lower bound for $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace $u$ by $A^{-1}v$ in the first chain of inequalities. Then use that $A^{-T}A^{-1}$ is positive definite.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!